# Firebase: Why Assign Firestore .onSnapshot to Variable?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looking at [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) is shows below as an example of how to attach a realtime update listener to Firestore data. My question is, why would I ever need to assign the listener to a variable? In other words, I understand that one might assign a promise to a variable so it could be `return`ed or `await`ed or `.push`ed to an array but none of that seems to apply to a realtime listener, unless I am missing the point? ...why assign `.onSnapshot` to a `var`?

```
var doc = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

var observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // ...
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows you to remove the observer later. In your case you'd unsubscribe by calling `observer()`, which is why we usually call this `unsubscribe` as in the section on [detach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

Comment: If there is **no** error, you'll use `unsubscribe()` to stop receiving notifications.

Comment: In a single-page web app there are many more scenarios where you detach a listener. So think of each separate HTML+JS that you have in mind now, as a part of a single web page instead.

Comment: In other words, __the reference is the variable to the onSnapshot method__. That's how the SDK works. So, layering on another variable violates the DRY principle. (unless I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 0):

The  [firebase.firestore.CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) or 
[firebase.firestore.DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) is the required variable to call `.onSnapshot` method. A single generic `muteListener` function can receive any reference to mute/unsubscribe. Assuming you're listening to an address document:

```
var shipToLocationDocument = null;

function muteListener(ref){
    return ref.onSnapshot(() => {});
}

shipToLocationDocumentListener = function () {
    return shipToLocationDocumentRef.onSnapshot(function (shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot) {
        //callback function to fire
        shipToLocationDocumentStateHandler(shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot error " + error.message);
    });
};
//call the function
shipToLocationDocumentListener();

//callback function
function shipToLocationDocumentStateHandler(shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot){
    if(shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot.exists){
        shipToLocationDocument = shipToLocationDocumentSnapshot;
        displayShipToLocation(shoppingCartDocument.data().shipTo); //actually we have all the info here already
    } else {
        shipToLocationDocument == null;
    }
}
```